# self cannot run the right method when collision happens

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, nsmutablearray, collision

I create a NSMutableArray which has 3 nodes, when hero collide with them, self runs 3 different methods(obj_1->method_1, obj_2->method_2....)My problem is when hero collide with obj_1, self sometimes runs method_2, but sometimes it runs well....it seems like "self" mix up with these 3 methods. I don't know which part of my code has gone wrong.

```
-(void)randomLetter{


obj_array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:3];

obj_1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@“1.png"];
obj_1.name = @“1”;

obj_2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@“2.png"];
obj_2.name = @“2”;

obj_3 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@“3.png"];
obj_3.name = @“3”;



[obj_array addObject: obj_1];
[obj_array addObject: obj_2];
[obj_array addObject: obj_3];



NSUInteger random_obj = arc4random()%obj_array.count;

obj_x = [obj_array objectAtIndex:random_obj];
[obj_array removeObjectAtIndex:random_obj];


obj_x.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius: obj_x.size.width/2];
obj_x.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
obj_x.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = objCategory;
obj_x.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = heroCategory;

obj_x.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width*1.1, self.size.height*0.5);
SKAction *obj_action= [SKAction moveToX:-self.size.width*1.1 duration:5];


[obj_x runAction:obj_action];
[self addChild: obj_x];
}


-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{

SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;
if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask<contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) {
    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;
}
else
{
    firstBody=contact.bodyB;
    secondBody=contact.bodyA;
}


    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & heroCategory ) !=0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & objCategory)!=0) {

        [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@“1” usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {

            _timeIsUp = NO;

            [obj_x removeFromParent];

           [self method_1];


        }];


        [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@“2” usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {

            _timeIsUp = NO;

            [obj_x removeFromParent];

            [self method_2];

        }];


        [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@“3” usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {

            _timeIsUp = YES;

            [obj_x removeFromParent];

            [self method_3];                
        }];

      }
}
```

Comment: When do you call `randomLetter()`?

Comment: as for my own question, i think i konw why. when obj_2 appears in the scene,the obj_1 hasn't remove from parent. i remove obj_1 before obj_2 appears , it runs well...

Comment: @WangYudong I call randomLetter() in a Timer, for 5 timeinterval, it fires

Comment: Since you know the reason now, have you resolved your problem? Or does my solution work?

Comment: @WangYudong i check object_1‘s x position in update method, remove it earlier, and it works. but i think your solution is better, i have tried and it also works well with concise code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to call `method_n` when the hero collides with `obj_n` (n=1,2,3), I think the following method is more clear. Have a try and tell me if you have any problems.

```
if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & heroCategory) !=0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & objCategory)!=0) {
    if ([secondBody.node.name isEqual:@"1"]) {
        _timeIsUp = NO;
        [secondBody.node removeFromParent];
        [self method_1];
    } else if ([secondBody.node.name isEqual:@"2"]) {
        _timeIsUp = NO;
        [secondBody.node removeFromParent];
        [self method_2];
    } else if ([secondBody.node.name isEqual:@"3"]) {
        _timeIsUp = NO;
        [secondBody.node removeFromParent];
        [self method_3];
    }   
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you remove `secondBody.node` from its parent instead of `obj_x`?

Comment: Thank you so much!!I am new to spritekit, i should learn more from you!

Comment: @WangYudong should "==" change into "isEqual:"?